# Ubuntu 16.04.02 LTS wifi network problem

Tags: networking, wireless

Sometimes when I have to connect to Wi-Fi network, The Wi-Fi option and the Wi-Fi networks don't show up when I click the Wi-Fi symbol.

It doesn't show a *Enable Wi-Fi* option but shows an *Enable Networking* option. Selecting or deselecting the *Enable Networking* option does nothing.

But after rebooting they show up.

Please tell me how to fix this up.

Comment: Please edit (https://askubuntu.com/posts/959281/edit ) your post and show us (properly formatted whith the `{}` tool) the contents of `/etc/network/interfaces`, and the results of `/sbin/ifconfig -a`.

Comment: Sometimes, when I "Disable" and then "Enable" Networking, the Wi-Fi APs do not appear and I have to execute the following command: `sudo service network-manager restart`. Try it

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.